# integration of Gaussian with prior mean

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution

I want to calculate the following Integration
$$\int \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}\right) \cdot \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu} \mid \mathbf{m},\left(\beta \boldsymbol{\Lambda}\right)^{-1}\right) d \boldsymbol{\mu}$$
and the answer is
$$ \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{m}, (1 + \beta^{-1})\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}\right)$$
How to get this answer？

Comment: What have you tried doing so far? The main trick to completing the integration is combining the exponentials into one and then completing the square within the exponential.

Comment: The question is more about the marginal distribution in a Normal - Normal model that about integration per se. The solution is available from standard Bayesian textbooks, if need be.

Comment: The technique is called *completing the square.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a conclusion in Session 2.3.3 of [PRML](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)

Given a marginal Gaussian distribution for x and a conditional Gaussian distribution for y given x in the form
$$\begin{aligned}
p(\mathbf{x}) &=\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}\right) \\
p(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{x}) &=\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{L}^{-1}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
the marginal distribution of y and the conditional distribution of x given y are given by
$$p(\mathbf{y})=\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{\mu}+\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{L}^{-1}+\mathbf{A} \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}\right)$$

Here, we have
$$p(\boldsymbol{\mu}) = \mathcal{N} (\boldsymbol{\mu}|\boldsymbol{m}, (\beta \mathbf{\Lambda})^{-1})$$
$$p(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{I}\boldsymbol{\mu}+0, \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1})$$
then, we have the marginal distribution
$$p(\boldsymbol{x}) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{I}\boldsymbol{m}+0, \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}+\boldsymbol{I}(\beta \boldsymbol{\Lambda})^{-1}\boldsymbol{I})=\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{m}, (1+\beta)\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1})$$

Hence,
$$\int p(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu})p(\boldsymbol{\mu})d\boldsymbol{\mu}=p(\boldsymbol{x})=\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{m}, (1+\beta)\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1})$$
Just as required.